# Unity - reconstruct position from depth

Tags: unity, shaders, fragment-shader

I am using Unity and I want to reconstruct position from depth and frustum corners in pixel shader.

I am doing this:

In my App, I calculate view-space corners of the far frustum plane and pass them to shader. (this is correct, I render spheres in world coordinates at corners and they are there).

In Full screen Vertex shader:
Select corner based on corner index calculated from texcoord. This is also correct, I have rendered colors.
This is passed to Pixel Shader as "ray"

In Pixel shader:

```
float3 normal;
float depth;
DecodeDepthNormal(tex2D(_CameraDepthNormalsTexture, i.uv), depth, normal);
depth =  Linear01Depth (depth);
position = depth * ray;
```

Reconstructed position is incorrect. The result I got for cube, that covers whole viewport is this:

[image]

But in reality, I should have this:

[image]

(or similar image with white, blue, pink for different handness)

My output is somehow "blured" around the middle. Why ?

Comment: When you pass the value from the vertex to the fragment shader are you binding it to a semantic?  I ask because it looks to me like the value is being interpolated between samples at each vertex, and that is causing the "blur" region where pixels between vertices are being drawn.

Comment: I suspect my comment wasn't very clear or I am misunderstanding the question.  If it isn't too long could you provide the body of your shader?  At least the vertex and fragment code and structures you use.

Comment: Have you tried setting the texture filter mode to 'point'? Just a thought.